# Importing YAML file to RStudio

Tags: r, yaml, rstudio

Hi I'm trying to import a YAML file (*.yamloo) into R Studio for analysis.

I'm using the YAML package for RStudio. Here's what I tried:

```
library(yaml)
data -> yaml.load_file("vn.yamloo")
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in yaml.load_file("vn.yamloo") <- data : 
target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Is a .yaml file the same as a .yamloo file; and is it overall possible to do this for RStudio?

Edit: That was really a retarded question sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Use `<-` instead of `->`.

Answer (score 5):

Use proper operator for assigning data to variables `=` or `<-`

```
install.packages("yaml") # Be sure you have yaml package installed 
library(yaml) 
data <- yaml.load_file("path_to_file/file.yaml")
```

> To be extra sure that your file will be load properly, try to use **absolue paths** or before including files set [**working directory**](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/workspace.html) `setwd("/path/to/the/directory")`

Answer (score 1):

These errors occur when you try to assign a value to a variable that doesn't exist, or that R can't treat as a name.

```
data -> yaml.load_file("vn.yamloo")
```

You are assigning  `data` to `yaml.load_file("vn.yamloo")`. so you needed to do the other way:

```
data <-  yaml.load_file("vn.yamloo")
```